# How should the app knows which items the user has selected after the first request?

Tags: android

I have Checkboxlist where the user can select some bus routes. After selecting the items I am sending a request to the server and getting response. After his first selecting I want to send his routes choice repeatedly to the server to get the longitude, latitude and route from the `bus` table on the server to update their location in the `Map` activity every 30 senconds. How can I manage that with android? How can the app knows which routes has he selected after the first request? How can I send the requests to the server repeatedly to get the current bus location in this case?

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

...
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for (int i : items) {
                        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(i);

                        if (ch.isChecked()) {
                            int a = Integer.parseInt(ch.getText().toString());
                            selected.add(a);

                        }
                    }

                    if (selected.size() > 0) {
                        String json = array_to_json(selected);
                        GetLLRD getLRL = new GetLLRD();
                        getLRL.post_selected(json, context);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No route was selected!");
                    }

                    for (int b : selected) {
                        System.out.println("CheckBox output: " + b);

                    }

                    selected.clear();

                }

            });
....
}


}
```

**GetLLRD class:**

```
public class GetLLRD {
    Context mContext;

    public void post_selected(String json, Context context) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);
        context = this.mContext;
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<ItemDTO>> {
        ArrayList<ItemDTO> data;


        @Override
        protected List<ItemDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

          .
          .
          .
          .

                                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (ItemDTO itemDTO : data) {
                    double latitude = itemDTO.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = itemDTO.getLongitude();
                    int route = itemDTO.getRoute();
                    String direction = itemDTO.getDirection();
                    System.out.println(latitude + ", " + longitude + ", "
                            + ", " + route + ", " + direction);

                }
          .
          .
          .
          .     


            return data;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDTO> result) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                    System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
                }
            }, 1*30 * 1000);

            if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Map.class);
                intent.putExtra("list",result);
                mContext.startActivity(intent); 

            }else{
                Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the dat is null in the GETLLRD class!!!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what buslines you want to track, you just need to *remember* them. Since you convert them to json and send this to the backend, you just store the json on a private member in your class.

For retrieving the data every 30 seconds, you could use `AlarmManager` to fire an event every 30 seconds. Don't forget to disable it when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and where have I to use the AlarmManager in the MainActivity, GetLLRD (onPostExecute method or where I execute the MyAsyncTask class ) or Map activity or in the onPostExecute method in the ?

Comment: I think your best bet is to make an IntentService and start it when the alarm goes off. Then you can get rid of the AsyncTask.